# How to ignore 401 and continue to read feeds

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I was given a json feed.

It does not need any user name or password to access.

It can be seen from google Chrome.

In the google Chrome developer tool, it also say status 401,
but still able to read data.

Then I try to use C#  web request or webclient, i get 401 and thrown , no longer able to continue.

So how does Chrome do it? and what should i do?

My C# code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = userAgent;
request.Timeout = timeOut;
((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = "application/json";
response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: If it definitely doesn't respond to the 401 with credentials, then it could be that the 401 response itself has the json, and so you could catch the `WebException` and work with its `Response`. This would be pretty bizarre though.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can "catch" the 401 exception that is thrown by HttpWebRequest and read the content off the WebException using code like this:

```
        try {
            // your code above
        }
        catch(Exception oEx)
        {
            if(oEx.GetType() == typeof(WebException))
            {
                HttpWebResponse wr = ((WebException)oEx).Response as HttpWebResponse;
                Stream dataStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string str = reader.ReadToEnd(); // str will contain the body of the HTTP 401 response
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```